# How can I simulate a backspace without using keyevent for my calculator app?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a delete button, and I created the following:

```
void onDelete() { 
        if (!getText().equals(strResult) && !isError) {
            mDisplay.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 67));
            strResult = ""; 
        } else {
            clear(false); 
        }
    }
```

So, when I press the buttons 456 on the calculator app, press delete, 45 remains on the small screen on top ( I don't really know what to call it, just the field that shows what your input is, just like a normal calculator has), exactly how it is supposed to be. However, this will only work if I 'select' the small screen on top. So, when I start the app, click the buttons 456, then press the del button, nothing happens, since I have to 'touch' the small screen on top first to let the cursor 'take place'. I want, however, that it is not necessary to select the calculator screen before using the delete button.

The code I used is based on [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ExactCalculator/+/caccbfb/src/com/android/calculator2/Logic.java):